# Every function on reals a sum of two surjective real functions?

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, measure-theory

From [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459054/writing-a-function-on-mathbbr-as-a-sum-of-two-injections), and the answer thereof, we can see that every real valued function on reals is a sum of two injective functions. Is the same true if we replace injectivity by surjectivity.

For continuous functions, we could use weierstrass polynomial approximation to get our desired answer (I hope), or some harmonic analysis. For discontinuous, much worse, for non-measurable functions, is it possible?

Extending this, is it possible to write a function as a sum of two bijective functions. Any hints?

Comment: The bijective case was answered on Twitter here: https://twitter.com/haskallcurry/status/1742997474262835471.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a simple proof that every function is the sum of two surjective functions.

Pick any onto functions $g:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ and $h: (-\infty, 0) \to \mathbb R$. Define
$$
g(x)= f(x)-h(x) \qquad \forall x < 0\\
h(x)= f(x)-g(x) \qquad \forall x \geq  0\\
$$

**Note:** It is actually possible to show any function $f$ can be written as $f=g+h$, where $g,h$ are surjective and satisfy the Intermediate Value Property. This can be done via the standard argument that each function on $\mathbb R$ can be written as the sum of two functions with the IVP.

Comment: But then, every such $f$ will be surjective right?

Comment: @vidyarthi No. Note that on $E$, the function $h$ is defined as $h=f-g$, which allows $f$ be anything.... Just to make this point crystal clear, when $f=0$ this construction produces $h=-g$... This works, even if $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: Ok, but I did not get what the use of the sets $O$ and $E$ are. Like, similar to your construction, I could take any two surjective functions on some restricted subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and then perform similar construction/extension right

Comment: I suggest you edit to omit the O, E stuff and just keep the simplification argument, which seems very clear.

Comment: @vidyarthi Yes, you can take any two **disjoint** subsets of $\mathbb R$ such that there is an onto function from each of them to $\mathbb R$. The construction only works if the two sets are disjoint, that's why I picked those. See the new solution.......

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Done :)

Comment: If you use sets that are disjoint and both size continuum on every interval (which your previous E O in effect did), you can use something like the Conway 13 function idea to make both $g$ and $h$ onto from every interval, which is a bit more than just IVT.

Comment: Actually the E O idea didn't quite achieve that, but one can achieve it.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins In the Conway 13 function, pick $g(x)=r$ or $h(x)=r$ only if it is a well-formed integer after an odd/even number of places. Or if the number of "special" characters is odd/even. Otherwise chose $g+h=f$.

Comment: Yes, or just look at the parity of the first symbol after it becomes well formed, and then omit that symbol (which is a little closer to your original E O idea).

Answer (score 11):

The bijective case is impossible. As a counterexample consider

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if } x = 0 \\
    0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Now consider the $x$ such that $h(x)=-g(0)$.

$x\neq 0$ since otherwise $f(0)=g(0)+h(0)=g(0)-g(0)=0≠1$.

Thus

$$f(x)=g(x)+h(x)=0$$

$$g(x)=-h(x)$$

$$g(x)=g(0)$$

But this implies $x=0$ by bijectivity of $g$. We have a contradiction.

Comment: Are you the twitter user?

Comment: @vidyarthi yes.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is yes.

**Theorem.** Every function $f:\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}\R\to\R$ is the sum of two surjective functions, $f=g+h$. Indeed, we can find such $g$ and $h$ that are surjective on every nontrivial interval.

**Proof.** Enumerate the reals in order type continuum $\R=\{x_\alpha\mid\alpha<\frak{c}\}$. We define $g$ and $h$ in stages, so that at every stage, fewer than continuum many values have been specified. To ensure surjectivity, we look at $x_\alpha$, and define $g(a)=x_\alpha$ for some $a$ for which $g(a)$ is not yet specified, and $h(a)=f(a)-g(a)$, and similarly $h(b)=x_\alpha$ and $g(b)=f(b)-h(b)$ for some $b$ similarly not yet used. And we also make sure $g(x_\alpha)$ and $h(x_\alpha)$ are defined, if they haven't yet been, by using $f(x_\alpha)/2$ for each. At each stage, the domains of the approximations to $g$ and $h$ are the same.

This defines two functions $g$ and $h$, and they will both be surjective, because at stage $\alpha$ we specifically placed $x_\alpha$ into their ranges, and we will have $g(x)+h(x)=f(x)$ for every $x$, since we ensured that property every time we defined another value of $g$ or $h$.

A simple modification of the argument will enable $g$ and $h$ to be surjective even when restricted to any interval, no matter how small. The reason is that we can enumerate the $x_\alpha$ along with rational intervals, and find $a$ and $b$ within the desired interval. $\Box$

The argument uses the axiom of choice, but perhaps there is an effective construction as in the [injectivity question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/459167/1946).

Comment: My older eyes blurred the subscript a bit, so, just to say it explicitly, in $g(a) = x_\alpha$, it's an $a$ in the argument but an $\alpha$ in the subscript.  (And I think "$a$ not yet specified" should perhaps be "$a$ not yet used", as with "$b$ not yet used".)

Comment: @LSpice Thanks, I've edited for clarity. And yes about $a$ and $\alpha$, the point being that we've placed $x_\alpha$ into the range of $g$ at stage $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks! And how about bijective. Will this construction not work (albeit with essential modifications)?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking it might be modifiable for bijective. But there are a few interferring obstacles... Perhaps someone else will figure it out?